# Submit all checked radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to make a quiz app with the help of MEAN stack.After all the questions are attempted there will be submit button to submit all the checked radio buttons.Like for option1 it should be 1,for option2 it should be 2.Currently my answer mongoose model looks like this-

```
const answerSchema = new Schema({

                              userEmail: {
                                type: String, require:true
                              },
                              testId: {
                                type: String, require:true
                              },
                              questionId: {
                                type: String, require:true
                              },
                              userAnswer: {
                                type: String
                              },
                              correctAnswer: {
                                type: String, require:true
                              },
                              timeTakenEach: {
                                type: Number,
                                default: 1
                              }  //insecs

})
```

Should I make any changes to the mongoose model because after submission I have to compare the useranswer with the correct answer.I feel like the useranswer and correctanswer fields should be an array so that all the questions checked option can be stored one by one.On the other hand how will I submit all the test data at once for all questions.What should my angularjs controller function logic be like.

Comment: Better don't include `correctAnswer` in the answerSchema instead have it in the separate collection because it will extra space in the DB for each user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better don't include `correctAnswer` in the answerSchema instead have it in the separate collection because it will extra space in the DB for each user

```
const answerSchema = new Schema({

    userEmail: {
        type: String, require: true
    },
    testId: {
        type: String, require: true
    },
    questionId: {
        type: String, require: true
    },
    userAnswer: {
        type: String
    },
    timeTakenEach: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    }  //insecs

});

const questionAnswer = new Schema({
    questionId: {
        type: String, require: true
    },
    correctAnswer: {
        type: String, require: true
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually have an array of objects for all the test questions in angular. After the completion of every question, keep pushing object to this array.

```
[
  {
    questionId: 123,
    userAnswer: 1,
    ...
  },
  {
    questionId: 123,
    userAnswer: 1,
    ...
  },
];
```

Finally when the test is complete, submit it to the API. On the other hand, keep your schema structured. Do not keep redundant data like email. You can simplify this as follows.

```
answerSchema = {
  userInfo: {
    name: 'abc',
    email: 'abc@xyz.com',
    attemptedOn: ...,
    ...
  },
  testMetaData: {
    testId: 1,
    testName: 'ABC Test',
    ...
  },
  attemptedAnswers: [{
    questionId: 1,
    attemptedAnswer: 2
  },
  ...
  ]
};
```

Comment: But what if the user changes  the option again.

Comment: You have questionId for every answer on your local array. So basically before pushing into the array, you can filter the elements. if answer for that questionId already exists, then update the same object using index. Filter Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: Thank You! Can you please have a look at this.Are these models correctly organized. https://jsfiddle.net/rahuljhawar88/s3qxpswm/

Comment: Looks good. But totalCorrectAnswers and totalWrongAnswers, both are not required. Only one is enough. Once you have any one of these, the other one can be calculated at runtime.